# how do i set up a linear system for two second degree polynomials?

Tags: linear-algebra

I need to set up a linear system for the following:

$\begin{equation}
  f(x)=\begin{cases}
    p_1(x), & \text{for $5 \leq x \leq 8$}\\
    p_2(x), & \text{for $8 \leq x \leq 10$}
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}$

where $p_1$ and $p_2$ are second degree polynomials, $p_1$ goes through the points $(5,40)$ and $(8,50)$
and $p_2$ goes through the points $(8,50)$ and $(10,65)$,
and at $x=8$ $p_1$ and $p_2$ have the same slope.

I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around this and would appreciate some pointers on how to think about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $p_i(x)=a_ix^2+b_ix+c_i$ then you need:

$$\begin{align}p_1(5)&=25a_1+5b_1+c_1=40\\
p_1(8)&=64a_1+8b_1+c_1=50\\
p_2(8)&=64a_2+8b_2+c_2=50\\
p_2(10)&=100a_2+10b_2+c_2=65\end{align}\\
p_1’(8)=2\cdot 8a_1+b_1=2\cdot 8a_2+b_2=p_2’(8)$$

This is five equations in six variables, so you should be able to find $a_1,b_1,c_1,a_2,b_2,c_2.$

If a solution exists, it won’t be unique.